# Angular 2 executing observables in a series

Tags: angular, observable

I have the following method:

```
 getProject(name) {
  this.ProjectName = name;
  //Friendly URL to ID --> FIRST OBSERVABLE
   this.af.database.object('/friendly_urls/' + name).take(1).share().map((data) => {
    //ID to data --> SECOND OBSERVABLE
     this.af.database.object('/Project/' + data.$value).take(1).map((ProjectData) => {
       console.log("Received Project data");
      this.ProjectData = ProjectData;
    });
  },
  error =>  {
    console.log(error);
    /* TODO: Permission blocked page */
    this.router.navigate(['']);
  });
}
}
```

I have 2 observables: The first observable, which executed first, and second one - which is executed right after him.

I tried to understand how to use [this](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/combining-multiple-rxjs-streams-in-angular-2.0) in my case and couldn't figure it out.

How I can execute this observables in a series without observable inside observable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `switchMap` to take the value from the first observable and use it as the seed to the 2nd observable. First you setup (compose) the stream:

```
projectData$ = this.af.database.object('/friendly_urls/'+name).share().switchMap(
    data => this.af.database.object('/Project/'+data.$value)
).take(1);
```

Then when you want to pull the data, just `subscribe`:

```
projectData$.subscribe(
    projectData => this.ProjectData = projectData,
    error => console.log(error);
)
```

[More about `switchMap`](https://gist.github.com/btroncone/d6cf141d6f2c00dc6b35#switchmap)

Comment: Hey thanks! But if I subscribe to `projectData$`,the `ProjectData` variable will be the observable of `this.af.database.object('/Project/'+data.$value)` and not the actual information I need (which is the subscription to this observable)

Comment: That leads that I need to make 2 subscriptions just like before one after another. `ProjectData.subscribe((data) => { this.RealProjectData = data } );`

Comment: @Elikos I am aware that `database.object` returns an Observable. That's why I use `switchMap` instead of `map`.  Have you tried my solution already and it failed or are you making a predicting about what will happen?

Comment: I'm sorry! Been using `.map` all way long. It works awesome! Thanks you.

Comment: Can you post an example how to do the same with 3 observables, depend on each other?

Comment: @Elikos Think of this operation as a stream. If you want to chain a 3rd observable to the stream, just call `switchMap` on the previous result.  `db.object(...).switchMap(data1 => db.object(...)).switchMap(data2 => db.object(...)).take(1)`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the static `concat` operator, which subscribes to the first observable and after completion to the second one.

```
let obs1 = this.af.database.object('/friendly_urls/' + name).map(data => data.$value);
let obs2 = this.af.database.object('/Project/' + data.$value).map(project => this.ProjectData = project);

let concatenatedObservables = Observable.concat(obs1, obs2);

concatenatedObservables.subscribe();
```

More on that here http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concat

Comment: This won't work b/c author is using `data` returned from obs 1, as an input to obs 2.  `concat` runs the two in independent contexts.